# How to define a persistent property in JXA

Tags: osascript, javascript-automation

In AppleScript I would write

```
property foo: "value"
```

and the value would be saved between runs. How can I do this in Javascript for Automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript for Automation doesn't have a direct parallel for the persistent property (and global value) mechanism of AS, but it does have `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, which work well for simple serialisation and retrieval of state.

Perhaps something broadly like:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var a = Application.currentApplication(),
        sa = (a.includeStandardAdditions = true, a),
        strPath = sa.pathTo('desktop').toString() + '/persist.json';

    // INITIALISE WITH RECOVERED VALUE || DEFAULT
    var jsonPersist = $.NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(strPath).js || null,
        persistent = jsonPersist && JSON.parse(jsonPersist) || {
            name: 'perfume',
            value: 'vanilla'
        };
    /*********************************************************/

    // ... MAIN CODE ...

    // recovered or default value
    sa.displayNotification(persistent.value);

    // mutated value
    persistent.value = "Five Spice"

    /*********************************************************/

    // WRAP UP - SERIALISE TO JSON FOR NEXT SESSION
    return $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(
        JSON.stringify(persistent)
    ).writeToFileAtomically(strPath, true);

})();
```

(A fuller example here: https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Examples#properties-which-persist-between-script-runs )

Or, for simple key-value pairs rather than arbitrary data structures, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31902220/1800086 on JXA support for writing and reading .plist